# Prefer Setters(Lombok) or normal assign

Tags: java, lombok

Which is costly operation(In terms of time taken)? 
1) Intialising fields by creating new object
2) Setting values of class by Setter in lombok.What happens in background when we do (A.setVariable()).

Comment: Have you done any benchmarking yourself?

Comment: whatever performance difference should be trivial. Constructor vs. Setter initialization is usually based on mutability concerns not performance. Maybe you want to set something that takes a long time, then you can still initialize a Supplier or other lazy initializer in the constructor. It's really a question of whether you have a mutable interface. For example, if you have a Person, you probably want to set Birthday in the constructor, but Address, Phone Number, or even Name could change, so you might want a Setter as well. But you should only care about performance when it actually matters.

Comment: @JoeC Most people asking this can't write a proper Java benchmark, unless they know [JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh). Benchmarking Java is much harder that expected.

Comment: To give you more information: 1. It doesn't matter if the setter is generated by Lombok or not. 2. Initializing the fields in the constructor might be faster than overwriting the defaults (0/null/false) or not, but it's definitely much better. Make you fields final if you can. 3. The JVM is damn smart and we needn't care about such microoptimizations, it inlines simple methods quite a lot. 4. If my comment does not answer you question, then please add details to your question and drop me a note in a comment containing the word `@maaartinus`.